# Login on new SE

Tags: support, login

In the past, it was fairly easy to create a SE account on a specific SE if you already had an account on a different SE. However, since they changed the login/sign-up page, I can't find this option anymore.

[image: Other options]

Where did it go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compared to the old one where you have to click "Log in using Stack Exchange" button to display the login form, the form provided by default is, [as you've already noticed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246621/login-on-new-se/246623#comment807359_246623), for SE credential. Just input the same credential you have used on other sites, then press "Log In" button. After that, you'll be prompted to confirm your new account as usual.

[image: new login page]

Comment: (I was also surprised when I got this page without any announcement from SE, I thought it's already live for everyone)

Answer (score 5):

Creating an account on a new site requires you to log into that site using *the same credentials you used on existing sites.* For instance, if you used the Stack Exchange login method, you'd...

1. Click the "Log in using Stack Exchange" button:

   [image]
2. Enter your username and password (yes, even if you *just did this* to log into, say, Stack Overflow) and press the "Log In" button:

   [image]
3. Confirm the creation of the new account:

   [image]

Comment: *facepalm* It doesn't say so explicitly, but the boxes in the middle (between Google/Facebook and the 'other' options) are for SE credentials. It used to be more explicit, now I got confused :)

Comment: Do note your screenshots apply for the old situation, not for the new. I guess you'll need a new set.

Comment: dammit, I didn't know that test was running, sorry. Yeah, I'll be needing *lots* of new screenshots.

Comment: I see :D So you have the old screenshots from your old answers? Wouldn't it be better to mark as dupe this question then?

Comment: No, it's more complicated than that @nicael - there are two different UIs running concurrently for different users, so I'd have to jump through a hoop or two to get new images. Probably worth waiting until after testing.