# Missing period in confirm new account dialogue

Tags: bug, grammar, sign-up

The following sentence in the *Confirm your new account* dialogue (this is when you visit a site on the network where you don't have an account and click *"Join this community"*) should end with a period:

> By clicking “Confirm new account”, you agree to our terms of service, privacy policy and cookie policy

[image: last sentence of confirm new account dialogue]

I found [a screenshot for 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246623) where the same sentence does end in a period, so it's something that's changed sometime between then and now.

In the meanwhile, I noticed that the same sentence does end with a period in other parts of the site, for example in https://stackoverflow.com/teams/create/free:

[image: the same sentence in another dialogue]

Comment: From Stacks: https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#periods

Comment: Next grammar bug: [Missing Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) in confirm new account dialogue.